# Float to int casting bug?

Tags: c#, casting

Why does the code below give different results?!
I am VERY shocked about this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int myInt = (int)(5 * 1.4f);
    Console.WriteLine(myInt); //Outputs 6

    float myFloat = 5 * 1.4f;
    myInt = (int)myFloat;
    Console.WriteLine(myInt); //Outputs 7

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

They should both give the result 7, but the first gives me 6. And 5 * 1.4f should be 7.

Comment: what results are you getting?

Comment: I commented it in the code with "//" 6 and 7

Comment: @user1666620 read the comments in the code...

Comment: it's because of how floats are represented in memory

Comment: 5 * 1.3f = 6.99999988079071. Floating point numbers are not the numbers you learnt in Maths classes.